# isotope makes weird transform in element styles which destroys layout, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I want to have different divs with background images aligning next to each other without distances like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/71qpceqb/

I use bootstrap `row and col` to achieve this.

In the fiddle this somehow works like a charm, with my actually copied css-code!
Here you can see my current project (htaccess temporarely removed)
http://remake.stdesign.eu/projekte/
This makes weird jumps (wrong number of divs in one line at wrong Screenwidth) and has alot of distances between the divs when resizing and I can´t figure out where this comes from. I thought setting this up on fiddle would help me to figure out whats wrong... but fiddle works perfectly with my css!

I guess I miss something very simple.

(for the filter stuff I use isotope.js, but I don´t feel like this is important.)

**EDIT:** After some trying I came to this: https://jsfiddle.net/71qpceqb/1/ making `col-400-12` to adept in all widths and adding it into the isotope masonary. I also updatet the fiddle code with my relevant JS. The resault is: fiddle works, original side doesn´t. The only difference I can find is on the original side when I observe the element there is an elementstyle `transform: translate3d(278px, 250px, 0px);` which I don´t have in jsFiddle.

I can´t figure out why I have this transform and how to remove/prevent it. If anybody could look into it would be very appreciated!

Comment: Bootstrap is a 12 column layout your using 15

Comment: Also Isotop is effecting the layout by adding `postition: aboslute`

Comment: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/extras.html#bootstrap

Comment: I am not using 15columns. I use 5times col-md-3 I guess that´s what you mean. But this should result into 4divs in 1st and 5th in 2nd line. And thats exactly what I want, which isn´t working.
But you are right with the Isotope, deactivating it solves the problem (could have tried that earlier....). Anyway I try to fix this now and let you know how I solve it

Comment: @NooBskie I added some new information, still struggling here, can´t figure out where those transform stuff is coming from :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after many hours spent on this, it seems to work now.

Reason why this occured for me and worked in fiddle:

I used 2.5 and fiddle was the 3.0 version. Never thought about this could be the reason!

Anyway, newest version works fine!